# PDO / PHP: How to echo a specific metakey value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I do have database with meta_key and meta_value for each of my users. I want to echo one value like the last_login only. How can I do this?

I'm not used to work with arrays and with a table like this.

`$result[meta_key][last_login]` is not working ;)

Thanks!

My database table:

```
id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

Some values:

```
3, 2, last_login, 2017-06-25 15:29:52
4, 2, name, Michael
5, 2, lastname, Leahcim
6, 3, last_login, 2017-06-04 07:29:52
7, 3, name, Peter
8, 3, lastname, Retep
```

My query:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `usermeta` WHERE  `user_id` =2");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
```

The Array I get:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 3
[0] => 3
[user_id] => 2
[1] => 2
[meta_key] => last_login
[2] => last_login
[meta_value] => 2017-06-25 15:29:52
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Add it to your query

```
   $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `usermeta` 
          WHERE  `user_id` =2 and meta_key='last_logon'";
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: But I also want to be able to get other values like the lastname later. So adding it to the query isn't an Option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  `usermeta`  WHERE  `user_id` =2 AND meta_key='last_logon'")->fetchall();
print_r($sth);
?>
```

Comment: But what if I want to echo user_id instead of last_login?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` is exact the parameter you actually need.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `usermeta` WHERE `user_id` = 2';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
var_dump($rows);
```

More details: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#unique